# how to make axis2 return gzipped response

Tags: apache-axis

By default axis2 returns regular(plain text xml) response. My goal - find some cfg property to make axis2 return gzipped response.

Anybody?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You configure this via the client, not the server

http://wso2.org/library/230#GZIP

Set this options flag to true
`org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.MC_GZIP_REQUEST`
to send your client request gzipped

Set this options flag to true
`org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.MC_ACCEPT_GZIP` to request that the server respond with a gzipped response

Comment: 1) I havn't java client, rather Delphi one
2) second option doesnt work, I checked this through HTTPAnalyzer utility.

Thanks anyway!

Btw org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants has extremely what I need - MC_GZIP_RESPONS. But__ this property doesnt work as well.